# Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA gives invalid character issue for findOne(…) on Oracle database

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ora-00911

My setup : Spring boot, using spring-data-jpa, Oracle 11g. I have same setup mentioned here on url,

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

It works for hsqldb. I want to work with Oracle. So, I created the table in Oracle db.
But, when I switch from in-memory/filesystem hsqldb to Oracle. It gives me issue.

```
WARN 3676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 911, SQLState: 22019
ERROR 3676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00911: invalid character

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.mycustompackage.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:92)
    at com.mycustompackage.ErrorPageFilter.access$0(ErrorPageFilter.java:87)
    at com.mycustompackage.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.mycustompackage.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:172)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.findByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycustompackage.controller.CustomerController.generator(CustomerController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:384)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

The select query which it generates, can be executed in sqldeveloper! Can anyone help me with this?

**Update 1**

Updated detailed stack trace above for repository.findByName("test").

I have a spring boot setup with my own datasource, EntityManagerFactory & TransactionManager configuration.

If I run findAll, it works. 
I also found out that, when i execute bare select query such as

> select * from customer where name = 'test'

It works!

But, when I use namedParameterJdbcTemplate and pass parameter, it gives above issue of 'invalid character'!

```
String sql = "select * from customer where name = :name";
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
paramMap.put("name", "test");
List<Map<String,Object>> objList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, paramMap);
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Sure.. adding stacktrace and some more information I gathered.

Comment: I'd suggest you debug into the Hibernate classes and maybe file a ticket with them. Seems like it's generating invalid SQL.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. That helped. I found the issue! It was in hibernate configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, I had some extra configuration on data source properties set.

processEscapes -> set to false.

When I turned this on, it gave me actual issue. The issue was, one of the columns I had named differently (camel case) than in table (underscore based).

So, after fixing the name in hibernate entity, making it underscore based name, it worked finally!

Column name defined in @Entity was firstName.
While in table the column name was first_name.

Just because I set DriverManagerDataSource -> setConnectionProperties with 
processEscapes = false

It was giving me wrong message! 
When I turned it to true, it gave me column identifier missing issue. Which led me to fix it :)

Comment: I had set hibernate.naming_strategy. 'ImprovedNamingStrategy'

But it seems, it did not work for column naming!

Answer (score 0):

This error is also caused if you use positional parameters ($1, $2) in an inner select.
As in

```sql
... FROM tablename WHERE keyfield= $1 and insert_date = ( select min (create_date) from tablename WHERE keyfield = $1)
```

Changing from positional to named parameters fixes the problem, ie... where keyfield `= :paramName`